# How to implement add favorite feature for recipes app using firebase and flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement to add favorite features for recipes app using firebase and flutter.

I made 2 models first one is **RecipeModel** and the second is **FavoriteRecipeModel**
All contain the data about the recipes but the FavoriteRecipeModel has boolean var for update the value when the user clicks the button from false to true and I want save the favorite by the id of the user.

**Idea: When the user press the button all data of the recipe will be transformed to **favouriteDataCollection** and the button will be a toggle in the same button that will also remove the recipes from favouriteDataCollection.**

Database file

```
final CollectionReference favouriteDataCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(kFavouriteRecipesCollection);

  Future updateFavourite(FavouriteRecipesModel favouriteRecipesModel) async {
    await favouriteDataCollection.doc().set({
      kFavouriteTitle: favouriteRecipesModel.title,
      kFavouriteCookingTime: favouriteRecipesModel.cookingTime,
      kFavouriteIngredients: favouriteRecipesModel.ingredients,
      kFavouritePreparation: favouriteRecipesModel.preparation,
      kFavouritePublishedDate: favouriteRecipesModel.dateTime,
      kFavouriteNumOfLikes: favouriteRecipesModel.numOfLikes,
      kFavouriteRecipeImage: favouriteRecipesModel.imgPath,
      kFavouriteServings: favouriteRecipesModel.servings,
      kIsFavourite: favouriteRecipesModel.isFavourite,
      kRecipeId: favouriteRecipesModel.recipeId,
      kFavouriteRecipeCat: favouriteRecipesModel.recipeBundleName,
      'uid': favouriteRecipesModel.userId,
    });
  }

  List<FavouriteRecipesModel> getFavouriteRecipes(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return FavouriteRecipesModel(
        title: doc.data()[kFavouriteTitle],
        cookingTime: doc.data()[kFavouriteCookingTime],
        servings: doc.data()[kFavouriteServings],
        imgPath: doc.data()[kFavouriteRecipeImage],
        ingredients: List.from(doc.data()[kFavouriteIngredients]),
        numOfLikes: doc.data()[kFavouriteNumOfLikes],
        recipeBundleName: doc.data()[kFavouriteRecipeCat],
        dateTime: doc.data()[kFavouritePublishedDate],
        preparation: List.from(doc.data()[kFavouritePreparation]),
        favouriteId: doc.id,
        recipeId: doc.data()[kRecipeId],
        isFavourite: doc.data()[kIsFavourite],
        userId: doc.data()['uid'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<FavouriteRecipesModel>> get favouriteRecipes {
    return favouriteDataCollection
        .where(kIsFavourite, isEqualTo: true)
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(getFavouriteRecipes);
  }

  Future isFavourite(bool val) async {
    await favouriteDataCollection.doc(uid).update({
      kIsFavourite: val,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are u using firestore? And Can u be more specific to your question

Comment: yes using firestore

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Comment: also, I added the idea in question

Comment: Did you understand the problem?